# Flutter build gradle failed while trying to make a release android app apk

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to release an apk for android. It is also not running now and not being able to release the apk.

I get following error

```
* Where:                                                                
  Build file '/Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/android/app/build.gradle' line: 77
                                                                    
* What went wrong:                                                      
 Could not compile build file '/Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/android/app/build.gradle'.
```

> startup failed:
> build file '/Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/android/app/build.gradle': 77: expecting '}', found '' @ line 77, column 47.
> om.google.gms.google-services'
> ^

```
 1 error                                                               
                                                                    
                                                                    
 * Try:                                                                  
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to 
  get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                    
 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                    
 BUILD FAILED in 797ms       


Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

**Line number 77 is**
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

All code in `app/build.gradle`

```
        def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }

    def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
        throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
    }

    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }

    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"


    def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
    def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))


    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28

        lintOptions {
            disable 'InvalidPackage'
        }

        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "se.forehand"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 5 //flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName "5.1" //flutterVersionName
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        signingConfigs{
            release{
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }

    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Seems you have syntax error in `android/app/build.gradle`. Add its code to question

Comment: edited please check

Comment: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` is the line 77..

Comment: @HkmSadek, add info about `line 77` to the question.

Comment: Edited again. I can see one line only in the editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add "}" to line 67!

Comment: where is `flutter.gradle` file? there is none exists. please formate the answer with correct file name

Comment: thanks, working, cannot believe i didn't touch that code so .// thanks